# how to calculate 24 hours format into minutes in Angular please anyone send typescript code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need Typescript code for converting 24 hours time format into minutes.

Example=> 1.00 = 60 minutes

```
      1.30 = 90 minutes.
```

please send code for that

Comment: Why does 1.3 = 90? Shouldn’t it be 1.5? If so, then multiply by 60?

Comment: Bro we give input 1.30 for 1 hour and 30 minutes i wanna calculate total minutes for total hours.  Are u clear with that?

Comment: Please consider your tone. 1.3 isn’t standard for converting decimal to minutes. It makes things a lot more difficult than necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the input will be always in x.xx format

```
let time: string = "1.30";
let timeArray = time.toString().split('.').map(data => parseInt(data));
let minutes = (timeArray[0] * 60) + timeArray[1];
console.log(minutes+ " minutes");
```

Comment: Sadly this will output 63 minutes and not the 90 the OP is wanting.

Comment: Super Bro.. Thank you Got the output. :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Go and Do code

Answer (score 0):

```
let time: String = '1.30';
console.log(parseInt(time.split('.')[0]) *60 + parseInt(time.split('.')[1]));

// parseInt() typescasts string in number
// split() converts an string in array
```

for refernece
[split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)